# Multiple Document Upsert in MongoEngine

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine

I have been really struggling to get multi-doc upserts to work in `Mongoengine` for Python.  I may not be thinking about the query structure correctly or how the mongoengine documents actually work.

Currently, I have to upsert each document individually and it's awfully inefficient.  The process is that i'm receiving messages, generating mongoengine documents, storing them in a list, and then attempting to pass that to a collection, but it doesn't work at all.

code looks like this:

```
new_docs = []

for data in data_for_docs:
    new_docs.append(create_doc(data))

Definitions.objects.update(new_docs, upsert=True, multi=True)
```

I've read a few posts that show the method `to_mongo`, but i'm not sure how that could help in this instance.

Comment: Would [bulk write](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#bulk-write-operations) be helpful here?

Comment: @Joe That's using pymongo; this is mongoengine.  Think I would need to convert my document objects somehow from mongoengine to be compatible with pymongo.